# AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, async-await, axios

I am developing a form using react-hook-form and while submitting all the details I am facing 404 error.
Below is the server side code:

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "1234",
  database: "registration",
});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected to MySQL Database");
});

app.post("/users", async (req, res) => {
  const formData = req.body;
  const sql = "INSERT INTO users SET ?";
  connection.query(sql, formData, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    res.send("User registered successfully");
  });
});

app.get("/api/users", (req, res) => {
  const sql = "SELECT * from users";
  connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
  });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

Here is the client side code:

```
const onSubmithandler = (data) => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/users", data)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        reset();
        setMessage("User registered successfully");
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };
```

I have tried developing with axios and also with async, await but it is producing the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the request that the request is to `localhost` and need to add `localhost` to post url

```
const onSubmithandler = (data) => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:YOUR_PORT/user/register", data)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        reset();
        setMessage("User registered successfully");
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };
```

If you have declared app by `app.use('/api/v1', ...)` or something like that then you need to append this also to your url like

`http://localhost:YOUR_PORT/api/v1/user/register`

Comment: I have edited the server side and the client code in the post. Can you please have a look at the codes and comment if any changes are to be made?

Comment: Thank you for the help. It has been solved.